# How can I access an injected variable in a different class in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

```
private final ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

@Autowired
public MainController(ExampleRepository exampleRepository) {
    super();
    this.exampleRepository = exampleRepository;
}
```

How can I access this injected exampleRepository variable by a static method in a different class?

Comment: You don't, and you shouldn't. If that other class needs the repository, it should have it injected there.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I'll try that. thanks